# How to detect overflow HTML elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, typescript

I have created a navigation bar with div(s) within it.

When i zoom-in, I hide the div's moving out of navigation bar through `css [overflow:hidden]`.

My goal is to create a java-script variable which will tell me what all div's are out of navigation Bar( hidden because of overflow), as i need to add them into collapsible menu which appears when even a single div is out of navigation Bar.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare scrollWidth/scrollHeight with clientWidth/clientHeight of the element.

```
if (e.scrollWidth > e.clientWidth){/*overflow*/}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pdrk50a6/

Edit: I do not know your root element, yet in the end it is going to be something like this.

```
document.body.onresize = function(){
    var tR = [];
    var tL = document.querySelectorAll('div');

    for(var i=0, j=tL.length; i<j; i++)
        if (tL[i].scrollWidth > tL[i].clientWidth) tR.push(tL[i])

    //Do whatever you need with the tR elements (overflown)
}
```

Comment: Ok, but can you say to me how can I detect when it changes, or the event generated when a zoom in happened?

Comment: What kind of zoom are we talking about (action & device | custom made)?

Comment: I think action, the zoom I'm talking about is performed by CTRL+ (zoom-in) and CTRL- (zoom-out)

Comment: I am not aware of any specific cross browser event fired on that action. There are ways to detect it, yet that would be another question/topic.

Comment: @Pinturikkio document.body.onresize works on modern browsers (Chrome & IE9+), just to say if you are interested.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80397/discussion-between-lain-and-pinturikkio).

Comment: It works properly with document.body.onresize !! Thx :)

Comment: You are welcome. If you have no additional questions on this topic, feel free to accept the answer, so further fellowers will see that your case got solved.

Comment: grr.. the overflow brings my overflown element on new paragraph and therefore it doesn't identify which element is overflown. can u help me?

Comment: I've found another way, but I accept your answer however for your commitment